# Как отменить действие перехода назад в браузере

Tags: javascript

Как отменить переход на предыдущую страницу, нажав на кнопку назад в браузере?
Отслеживаю само событие 'popstate' но проблема в том, что когда это событие срабатывает браузер уже одной ногой на другой странице и не могу найти способ отменить переход. Это нужно что бы пользователь выполнив изменения на сайте не перешел назад не сохранив изменения

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload` Если пользователь отменит, то не уйдет со страницы... Явно запретить вы не сможете.

Comment: Предупреждение появляется, что Вы пытаетесь покинуть старницу, но если нажимаю отмена все равно покидает страницу

Answer (score 0):

Без живого примера, того что вы пытаетесь сделать, тяжело ответить на ваш вопрос, но если у вас всё верно, то вам нужно внести условие в обработку вашего действа и прервать его при помощи [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) :

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', (e) => {
  if ('dataSaved' === false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // дальнейшие действия на этот случай,..
  }
});
```

где 'if ('dataSaved' === false)' — ваше условие.)